# Let $L/K$ be a field extension. When $x\otimes1=1\otimes{x}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, tensor-products

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension. Let's consider $R＝L\otimes_K{L}$.
> In $R$, when $x\otimes1=1\otimes{x}$ ?

I understand when $x∈K$, $x\otimes1-1\otimes{x}=1\otimes{x}-1\otimes{x}=0$, but I don't understand why it is nonzero when $x$ is not in $K$.
Could you give me explanation why $x\otimes1-1\otimes{x}$ is not zero when $x∈L\setminus K$?

Comment: I guess you would like to factor $x$ out and put it at second place. However this is valid if and ONLY IF $x\in K$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$x\otimes 1\neq 1\otimes x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286642/x-otimes-1-neq-1-otimes-x)